# Проблема с нугетами в гитлаб

Tags: gitlab, nuget

Есть репозиторий в гитлаб, в котором хранятся нугеты. Есть настроенный CI/CD для публикации. Всё окей, всё проходит. Система версионирования основана на тегах + build-version для побочных веток, из-за чего под основным тегом может опубликоваться более 1 сборки нугета.

В какой-то момент перестали искаться пакеты в источнике с версией, под которой было опубликовано несколько повторных сборок.

Вопрос такой: из-за чего происходит и как это можно чинить? Сейчас нашел только способ с ручным удалением версии нугета, пересборкой и перехода к следующему, однако такой способ мало меня устраивает из-за большого количества нугетов в одном решении.